# Can not find NIC in test agent properties of load testing in VS2013

Tags: load-testing

[image]

As image displays, not NIC item available in NIC dropdownlist. The Test-Agent2 actually has 2 network adapters. any idea about this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
I had to run Visual Studio as administrator to list NICs.